# How to change dynamic language in angular-strap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I use angular-strap datepicker in my project. Unfortunately, I didn't find there opportunity for dynamic changing locale. I need to redraw datepicker on every `$localeChangeSuccess`, but I don't know how to do it. Plugin defines locale due to service `$locale`, but it defines only once on `init` stage.

Comment: What should happen to your datepicker when the locale has been changed?

Comment: It should change the names of months and weeks in current locale.

Comment: This is what the documentations says: `This module leverages the $locale service. You just have to load the proper i18n file to seamlessly translate your datepickers.`. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/ Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, i use it in my project, but this file is just needed for translating in current locale. But how the plugin to notify about changing locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, unfortunally [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) doesn't watch `$locale` changes. Initializing angular-strap with a specific `$locale` works very well but once the locale changed, angular-strap does not rerender his components. I could make it work with some tricks but this solution is not the best because its depending on `$timeout`'s and "force render stuff". Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90bk4cz6/5/). It would be much better to create a feature request at GitHub and make angular-strap rerender when `$locale` changed.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="padded">
    <select name="language" 
            ng-model="language" 
            ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in languages" 
            ng-change="changeLanguage(language)"></select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            ng-if="!someChange" 
            ng-model="myDate" 
            placeholder="Until" bs-datepicker>
    <div class="padded">Selected date: {{ myDate | date:'shortDate'}}</div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
angular.module('calendar', [
  'mgcrea.ngStrap.datepicker',
  'tmh.dynamicLocale'
])
.config(function (tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
  tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
})
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, tmhDynamicLocale, $timeout) {

  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.someChange = false;
  $scope.language = 'en-gb';
  $scope.languages = {
    'en-us': 'English (USA)',
    'en-gb': 'English (Great Britain)',
    'de-de': 'Deutsh (Deutsh)'
  };


  $scope.changeLanguage = function (language) {

    //set new language
    tmhDynamicLocale.set(language);

    //store selected date 
    var saveDate = angular.copy($scope.myDate);

    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.someChange = true;
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.someChange = false;
        $scope.myDate = saveDate;
      }, 150);
    }, 150);
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I will create feature request on angular-strap github page.

Comment: I closed my issue :)

Comment: @proJS Great, i followed you up on GitHub. Call me if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution with the ng-if but it caused me side effects that the ngModel stop updating after one selection in the timepicker.

I came out with another approach that works without removing the element:

Instead of giving the model a date I give it an object like:

```
$scope.pickerModel = { date: myDate, language: myLang }
```

and change the angular-strap code like that:

go to:

`controller.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) function...` in line: 3774

and change in the "else" from:

```
date = new Date(modelValue);
```

to

```
date = new Date(modelValue.date);
if (modelValue.language) {
   options.language = modelValue.language;
}
```

That's it!